# Suppose $0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,...$ is a sequence. What is the general term of this sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $$0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,...$$
be a sequence. What is the general term of this sequence?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51762/what-is-the-general-term-of-these-sequences?rq=1

Comment: What is meant by "general term"? A definition $a_k = f(k)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Who *needs* a general term for things like this? An expression "*1 for $n=3k$, 0 otherwise*" is about as good as it gets.

If you're still not convinced, go with ${1\over3}+{2\over3}\cos{2\pi n\over3}$.

Answer (score 7):

$$3T(n)=1+w^n+w^{2n}$$  where $w$ is a complex cube root of unity

So, for $$\underbrace{0,0,\cdots,0,0}_{(m-1)\text{ terms}},1$$

$$mT(n)=\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}(u^r)^n$$  where $u$ is a complex $n$th root of unity

Answer (score 0):

Consider

$a_{3k}$

and

$a_n$ for $n=3k-1$ and $n=3k-2$